# show count value based on condition in mysql

Tags: mysql

select count of instituteId based on countries.haveState. if haveState=1 then, Count(institutions.instituteid) is based on stateId like if(institution.stateId='1') then count Count(institutions.instituteid) otherwise count instituteId without stateId like below.

```
SELECT countries.countryid, 
       Count(institutions.instituteid) AS instituteCount 
FROM   countries 
       RIGHT JOIN institutions 
               ON countries.countryid = institutions.countryid 
WHERE  countries.countryid = '32' 
       AND countries.status = '1'
```

Comment: Your explanation is very hard to read / understand !

Comment: sorry,... my query is, want to get the count of institute based on condition  country have state value 1 then count with condition the state id otherwise then no need to use condition state id  for count institute id